# What is the path for the startup folder in windows 2008 server

Tags: windows

Is there a folder to keep programs to run while doing starting of the system. As like this "C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"??.

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: I need to run two line command file to open a connection to another VM shared folder. This serves simple and easy...:)

Comment: You should put your updates in the post itself, not in a comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Retrieves the full path of a known folder identified by the folder's `KNOWNFOLDERID`.

And, [`FOLDERID_CommonStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Default Path  `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`

There are also managed equivalents, but you haven't told us what you're programming in.

Comment: This is fine if you're on the system where you want to get at the folder. But it's less helpful if you're loading a remote filesystem from a different machine.

Answer (score 29):

In Server 2008 the startup folder for individual users is here:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup

For All Users it's here:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Hope that helps

Answer (score 11):

You can easily reach them by using the Run window and entering:

`shell:startup`

and

`shell:common startup`

[Source](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/1043-71-program-startup-windows-server-2012).